# ESB Management Console (ESB Toolkit 2.1) not showing data

Tags: biztalk, esb

I successfully installed the ESB Toolkit 2.1 on top of BizTalk 2010.

Everything seems to work fine. 
I created a sample app following Peter Kelcey's "BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.0--Part 1: Dynamic Routing and UDDI Integration" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/ee819071.aspx).

The message fails, but my problem is that I don't see anything in the **ESB Management portal** (or in the BAM portal, in the itinerary view).

I don't have any exception or anything, just no data.

I also checked the **EsbExceptionDb** database in SQL Server. And the connection strings in the portal web.config seem to be ok.

I must say that I installed the portal *from the samples source*, by rebuilding the solution and verifying all the configurations in IIS as per the documentation.

Thanks for any direction

Cos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update on this:

I saw that I couldn't access the ESB.Exception.Service app from either VS or browsing from IIS
I rebuilt and republished the ESB.Exception.Service app.
Now the localhost/ESB.Exceptions.Service/ responds properly.

Also, I used the sample test app that calls the localhost/ESB.ExceptionHandlingServices/ExceptionHandling.asmx and now it is able to write to the database.

The ESB Portal shows the fault data now.

Basically rebuilding it fixed it, but I don't know what was wrong to start with.

Cos